# Extract a type from a const string array

Tags: typescript

I know that in Typescript you can do this:

```
const someOptions = {
  a: "",
  b: "",
  c: ""
} as const 


type SomeType = keyof typeof someOptions
```

I would like to do something very similar but then using an array as input.

```
const someOptions = ["a", "b", "c"] as const;
type SomeType = ...
```

Is this possible?

An array is convenient because I can pass it directly to something like Joi.string().valid(). Also, I also don't have sensible values to define for these things in a key/value object so it feels silly to use an object as starting point.

Comment: ...did you try it?

Comment: Haha, did you? It will give you a type with "0" | "1" | "2" | "length" | "push" etc... I need the values not the keys.

Comment: If you do keyof typeof it will, yes. They're the keys of the array type. Your question just shows an ellipsis, though; it's helpful to put what you've tried and what happened.

Comment: Thanks, but the ellipsis was meant to indicate that I didn't have a clue :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access `[number]` on the `typeof someOptions` array to get to the values as a union type:

```
const someOptions = ["a", "b", "c"] as const;
type SomeType = typeof someOptions[number]
// SomeType is:
// "a" | "b" | "c"
```